# Bulk Update Mysql Table Field From Api Using Eloquent

Tags: mysql, laravel, api

I'm trying to mass update existing records in my database from an Api call. I'm trying to update my Student table from from Infusionsoft Api. I can connect to the api, get the data but I don't know how to mass update the students info based on their Infusionsoft ID. I could have used Laravel Eloquent Mass Update by that is only setting a single value on the field you want to update.

These are the fields from my Student table as well as Infusionsoft Api fields.

```
-- Student Table --
 infusionsoft_id
 teach_id 
 firstname
 lastname 
 access 


 -- Infusionsoft Api Field --
Id
_Coach 
FirstName
LastName
_Access
```

I'm getting the data from the Infusionsoft Api call but trying to figure out on how to mass update the table with those data. All those students data in the Api are already in the database. Just need to mass update to keep data stored in the database update to the in Infusionsoft.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Do you have models set up? You're probably looking for [`->update([fields])`](https://laravel.com/api/5.4/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.html#method_update).

Comment: Eloquent doesn't have a way to mass update the way you want. Since you need to update each student based on their id, the right way would be to loop through the api result and update each student.